# Cant solve a debug error "ValidHeapPointer(Block)"

Tags: c, queue

Im trying to write a code, to learn queue.
The code worked for a while and then suddenly i have an error that sadly i couldn't solve while running the code, build solution brings no errors.

It seems to be triggered in the function "dequeueLast" and freeing memory allocation in "dequeue".

any assistance will be appreciated!

Im posting the whole code in case anyone would like to run it by himself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int  data;
    struct node *next;
}NODE;


typedef struct Queue
{
    NODE *head;
    NODE *tail;
} QUEUE;

void FREE(QUEUE *q);
void enqueue(QUEUE *q, int data);
int dequeue(QUEUE *q);
int empty(QUEUE q);
void PrintQueue(QUEUE q);
void initQueue(QUEUE *q);

void enqueue(QUEUE *q, int data)
{
    NODE *newnode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (newnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = data;
    if (empty(*q))
    {
        q->head = newnode;
        q->tail = q->head;
    }

    else
    {
        q->tail->next = newnode;
        q->tail = newnode;
    }
}


int dequeue(QUEUE *q)
{
    int data;
    NODE *tmp;
    if (empty(*q))
        return 0;
    else {
        tmp = q->head;
        q->head = tmp->next;
        if (q->head == NULL)
            q->tail = NULL;
        data = tmp->data;
        free(tmp);
    }
    return data;
}



int empty(QUEUE q)
{
    if ((q.head == NULL) && (q.tail == NULL))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


void PrintQueue(QUEUE q)
{
    int data;
    QUEUE tmp;
    initQueue(&tmp);
    while (!empty(q))
    {
        data = dequeue(&q);
        printf(" %d ", data);
        enqueue(&tmp, data);
    }
    while (!empty(tmp))
        enqueue(&q, dequeue(&tmp));



}
void FREE(QUEUE *q)
{
    while (!empty(*q))
        dequeue(q);
}

void initQueue(QUEUE *q)
{
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
}

int dequeueLast(QUEUE *q)
{
    int data;
    int savedData;
    QUEUE *tmpQ = (QUEUE*)calloc(1, sizeof(QUEUE));
    initQueue(tmpQ);
    while ((q->head) != (q->tail))
    {
        data = dequeue(q);
        enqueue(tmpQ, data);
    }
    savedData = q->tail->data;
    FREE(q);
    while (!empty(*tmpQ))
        enqueue(q, dequeue(tmpQ));
    FREE(tmpQ);
    free(tmpQ);

    return savedData;
}

int queueLength(QUEUE *q)
{
    int data;
    int counter = 0;
    QUEUE *tmpQ1 = (QUEUE*)calloc(1, sizeof(QUEUE));
    initQueue(tmpQ1);
    while (!empty(*q))
    {
        data = dequeue(q);
        enqueue(tmpQ1, data);
        counter++;
    }
    FREE(q);
    while (!empty(*tmpQ1))
        enqueue(q, dequeue(tmpQ1));
    FREE(tmpQ1);
    free(tmpQ1);

    return counter;
}

void main()
{
    int num, data, lengthQ;
    QUEUE *queue = (QUEUE*)calloc(1, sizeof(QUEUE));
    initQueue(queue);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter a number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &num);
        enqueue(queue, num);
    }
    printf("Original queue:");
    PrintQueue(*queue);
    printf("\n");
    data = dequeueLast(queue);
    printf("Queue after removal of last piece:");
    PrintQueue(*queue);
    printf("\n");
    lengthQ = queueLength(queue);
    printf("Queue length after removal is: %d\n", lengthQ);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Your queue is a linked list, your `PrintQueue` can iterate over this list *without* having to dequeue and enqueue elements all the time. Just do e.g. `for (NODE *node = q->head; node != NULL; node = node->next) printf("%d\n", node->data);`

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  regardless of what visual studio will allow, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Note in modern C, if there is no explicit `return( value );` statement in `main()` then the code will return an implicit 0.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int num, data, lengthQ;`  And `data = dequeueLast(queue);`  The variable `data` is being 'set', but never 'used'.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: OT: regarding: `QUEUE *queue = (QUEUE*)calloc(1, sizeof(QUEUE));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. 2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `if (newnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }`   1) this is no  'overflow' of the queue.  Rather it is a failure of the function: `malloc()`  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  3) when the error is from a C library function, then should also output (to `stderr) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` properly outputs both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
int dequeueLast(QUEUE *q)
{
    int data;
    int savedData;
    QUEUE *tmpQ = (QUEUE*)calloc(1, sizeof(QUEUE));
    initQueue(tmpQ);
    while ((q->head) != (q->tail))
    {
        data = dequeue(q);
        enqueue(tmpQ, data);
    }
    savedData = q->tail->data;
    FREE(q);
    while (!empty(*tmpQ))
        enqueue(q, dequeue(tmpQ));
    FREE(tmpQ);
    free(tmpQ);

    return savedData;
}
```

Most of this function does not do what you would want.

And the returned value is assigned to a local variable in `main()`, but not used.

Suggest:

```
void dequeueLast(QUEUE *q)
{
    NODE *current == q->head;
    NODE *previous = q->tail;

    while( current->next )
    {
        previous = current;
        current  = current->next;
    }

    if( previous )
    {
        previous->next = NULL;
        free( current );
        q->tail = previous;
    }
}
```

There are several reasons for the suggested changes, including the removal of all the unneeded queueing and dequeueing of each of the existing nodes in the queue and the fact that the data value in the last node in the queue is not actually used.

also, with a bit of re-arranging of the order of the functions, all the prototypes can be removed

also, in the function: `PrintfQueue()`  Do NOT create a complete new queue, rather just walk through the queue, similar to:

```
void PrintQueue(QUEUE *q)
{
    NODE *current = q->head;

    while ( current->next )
    {
        printf(" %d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

and all the calls to `PrintQueue()`  should be:

```
PrintQueue( queue );
```

since `queue` is already a pointer and it is much better to pass a pointer to the struct rather than the complete struct

OT:  regarding:

```
scanf_s("%d", &num);
```

when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful,  I.E.

```
if( scanf_s("%d", &num) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf_s to input a number failed" );
}
```

There are plenty more problems in the posted code, but the above should get you aimed in the right direction